# Integration of JSF 2 and Spring 4 (no Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, jsf, multi-module

I've been struggling for 2-3 weeks now with transforming my project (single module) into a multi module project where the modules are representing the layers of a multilayer architecture (i.e. persistence, business, domain...)

When the project was still a single module, everything worked together. I had my ManagedBean classes managed by JSF and enabled `@Autowired` for Spring with a workaround, so I could inject my Spring-managed classes into the jsf-managed beans. Now, this won't seem to work anymore, so I'm trying to clean my code up and orientate myself at some examples I've seen (one is the Maven archetype for jsf2 + spring 4 integration).

It seems, there are two ways suggested to do the Dependency Injection:

1. Do it per `@ManagedProperty` (But I don't want to do this all per JSF)
2. Do it per `@Autowired` and let Spring manage the Backing/Managed Beans (That's what I try to do)

Though many sources (even the Maven archetype, which is working) suggest to just annotate my Backing Bean class with Spring annotations (`@Component, @Scope("session")`), I always get the error

`Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'administration' resolved to null`

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
     </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd" >
<context:component-scan
    base-package="my.base.projectpackage" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured />

<!-- import the other context files for Spring -->
<import resource="classpath*:META-INF/*-springContext.xml"/>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2" metadata-complete="false">

<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

I've already tried to:

1. Enable Autowiring into a JSF managed bean (per [...].autowire(this) -> not working, **NPE** for the Service class)
2. Try it with @ManagedProperty on JSF annotated Service classes (not working, **NPE** for the Service class)
3. Try it with pure Spring classes (like mentioned above, not working **identifier resolved to null** for the managed bean)

I can compile and build the modules and the whole project without errors, and I've also not forgotten to put intermodular dependencies (like business module is depending on persistence module) into the pom.xml. Every module has packaging "jar" (except ofc the webapp module, which is war). Did I forget to mention something else?

I run the project on Tomcat 8 (though this should not be the source of the error).

Maybe someone of you has got a hint, idea or solution for me.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I got my project to work again and split it into multiple modules. But the only way to do this was to really copy + paste (argh! really..) my classes into the Maven archetype project and add some minor, not important fixes (like cleaning out my POM files). When it worked there, I was curious, copied the project files back into my old project and tried it there again. Surprisingly, it still didn't work, even though there was no difference anymore which could have caused it not to work. So, the mystery is still unsolved, but after all, I could continue with my work.

Thank you for your help (or for trying to help me, since this was a lost cause) @Tiny.

Comment: Did you register your beans in the `applicationContext.xml` file in your real code like `<bean id="beanService" class="com.example.Bean"/>`? Where `com.example.Bean` is a fully qualified class name (the bean).

Comment: `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`?

Comment: I already did try this (tried again after your comment), but did not change anything. I wonder, why in other projects it could work (JSF expressions directly referring to Spring Beans) but it wouldn't do this for my project.
Edit: <mvc:annotation-driven/> won't change anything either :/